# the proof of Van Kampen theorem in Hatcher's book

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Hatcher defines two moves that can be performed on a factorization of $[f]$，The second move is

Regard the term $[f_i]\in\pi_1(A_\alpha)$ as lying in the group  $\pi_1(A_\beta)$ rather than $\pi_1(A_\alpha)$ if $f_i$ is a loop in $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta$.

In the book,the author mentions that the move does not change the image of this element in the quotient group $Q=\ast_\alpha\, \pi_1(A_\alpha)/N$,by the definition of $N$,how to conclude the above conlusion,can anyone show me any examples to interpret the statement?

If we have $X=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$,$[f_1]\in \pi_1(A_1\cap A_3),[f_2]\in \pi_1(A_2)$,does it mean that $[f_1][f_2]$ and $[f_2][f_1]$ are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ is the normal subgroup of $*_\alpha \pi_1(A_\alpha)$ generated by all words of the form $i_{\alpha\beta}(\omega)i_{\beta\alpha}(\omega)^{-1}$ with $\omega \in \pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$.

Hatcher does not formulate the second move very precisely. He "really" means that if $g_j$ is a loop in $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$, i.e. $ [g_j] \in \pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$, then we are allowed to replace $[f_j] = i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j]) \in \pi_1(A_\alpha)$ by $[f'_j] = i_{\beta\alpha}([g_j]) \in \pi_1(A_\beta)$.

To understand this, note that by *definition* the word $[f_j][f'_j]^{-1}$ is contained in $N$. Similarly, since $[g_j]^{-1} \in \pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$, we see that also $[f_j]^{-1}[f'_j] =  i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j])^{-1}i_{\beta\alpha}([g_j]) = $ $i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j]^{-1})i_{\beta\alpha}([g_j]^{-1})^{-1} \in N$. This implies that if $w$ is an arbitrary word containing $[f_j]^\epsilon$, $\epsilon = \pm 1$, and the word $w'$ is obtained by replacing $[f_j]^\epsilon$ with $[f'_j]^\epsilon$, then $w,w'$ have the same equivalence class in $Q$. To see this, note that we can write $w = u [f_j]^\epsilon v$ and $w' =  u [f'_j]^\epsilon v$ with suitable words $u, v$ in $*_\alpha \pi_1(A_\alpha)$. Then $w(w')^{-1} = u [f'_j]^\epsilon v v^{-1} [f'_j]^{-\epsilon}u^{-1} = u [f'_j]^\epsilon [f'_j]^{-\epsilon}u^{-1} \in N$ because $[f'_j]^\epsilon [f'_j]^{-\epsilon} \in N$ and $N$ is a *normal* subgroup of $*_\alpha \pi_1(A_\alpha)$.

In your example you have $[g]\in \pi_1(A_1\cap A_3)$, $[f_1] = i_{13}([g]) \in \pi_1(A_1)$, $[f_2]\in \pi_1(A_2)$. With $[f_3] = i_{31}([g]) \in \pi_1(A_3)$ you see that $[f_1][f_2]$ and $[f_3][f_2]$ are equivalent, but it is not true that$[f_1][f_2]$ and $[f_2][f_1]$ are equivalent.

**Edited:**

Due to the discussion in the comments let me "go back to the roots".

A map $f : X \to Y$ is determined by its domain $X$, its range $Y$ and the rule of assignment $X \ni x \mapsto f(x) \in Y$. The range is an essential constituent of $f$. If you have a space $Y' \supset Y$, you may regard $f$ as map into $Y'$, but the precise interpretation is that you replace $f$ by the map $i \circ f : X \to Y'$ (where $i : Y \to Y'$ denotes the inclusion map). The maps $f$ and $i \circ f$ are *not the same* because the have different ranges (although you have $f(x) = (i \circ f)(x)$ for all $x  \in X$). Conversely, if you have a map $f' : X \to Y'$ such that $f(X) \subset Y$, you may regard $f$ as map into $Y$, but the precise interpretation is that there exists a unique map $f : X \to Y$ such that $f' = i \circ f$.

Precision is no nitpicking. This is of particular importance if you consider homotopy classes of maps. The range determines how much space is available for  deformations. Two non-homotopic maps $f, g : X \to Y$ may become homotopic in a bigger $Y' \supset Y$ which means that $i \circ f, i \circ g$ are homotopic. As an example take $id : S^1 \to S^1$ which is not null-homotopic, but becomes null-homotopic in $\mathbb R^2$.

Hatcher does not address this point, probably it seems self-evident to him. When he says that $g_{k-1} \circ f \circ g_k$ is a loop in $A_k$, he means that the map $g_{k-1} \circ f \circ g_k : I \to X$ has the property $(g_{k-1} \circ f \circ g_k)(I) \subset A_k$ and thus can be written as $g_{k-1} \circ f \circ g_k = \iota_k \circ \phi_k$ with  $\phi_k : I \to A_k$, where $\iota_k : A_k \to X$ denotes the inclusion map.

Then $[\phi_k] \in \pi_1(A_k)$ and you get $i_k([\phi_k]) = (\iota_k)_*([\phi_k]) = [\iota_k \circ \phi_k] = [g_{k-1} \circ f \circ g_k] \in \pi_1(X)$.

Comment: But $ i_{\alpha\beta}$ and  $i_{\beta\alpha}$ are inclusion maps, $i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j]) =[g_j],i_{\beta\alpha}([g_j])=[g_j]$.

Comment: No. $[g_j]$ is an element of $\pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$, but $i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j]) \in \pi_1(A_\alpha)$ which is different group. I denoted the lattter by $[f_j]$. By an *abuse of notation* you can write $[g_j]$ instead of $[f_j]$. This is Hatcher's imprecision. But $\pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$ is definitely not a genuine subgroup of $\pi_1(A_\alpha)$.

Comment: $\pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$ is not a subgroup of $\pi_1(A_\alpha)$? But according to the definition of fundamental group,any loop $f$ in $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ is also a loop in $A_\alpha$,so any homotopy class of $f$ in $\pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$ is also in $\pi_1(A_\alpha)$?Would you mind showing me a counterexample?

Comment: You can of course regard any loop in $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ as a loop in $A_\alpha$. The precise meaning is to use the inclusion-induced homomorphism $i_{\alpha\beta} : \pi_(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta) \to \pi_1(A_\alpha)$. But the elements $[g_j]$ and $[f_j] = i_{\alpha\beta}([g_j])$ are *not the same* and deserve a distinct notation. Note that in general $i_{\alpha\beta}$ is not an injection so that you cannot reconstruct $[g_j]$ from $[f_j]$. Take for example $A_1$ = open disk centered at $0\in \mathbb R^2$ and $A_2$ = $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$:$\pi_1(A_1 \cap A_2) =\mathbb Z,\pi_1(A_1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!

Comment: In the proof,we need to constrcut a loop $(f_1\cdot\bar{g_1})\cdot(g_1\cdot f_2\cdot\bar{g_2})\cdots(g_{m-1}\cdot f_m)$ which is homotopic to $f$,then we can conlude that $[f]$ is in the image of $\psi$,where $\psi:\ast_\alpha\, \pi_1(A_\alpha)\to \pi_1(X)$.I wonder what is a preimage of $[f]$? If $[f_i]\in \pi_1(A_i)$,then $\psi([f_1][f_2]\cdots[f_n])=[f_1][f_2]\cdots[f_n]$?

Comment: Your formula for $\psi$ is essentially correct, but what is the question? How to find to $f_i$ if you are given $f$? More precisely $\psi([f_1]...[f_n]) = i_1([f_1]) ... i_n([f_n])$, where $i_k : \pi_1(A_k) \to \pi_1(X)$ are induced by the inclusions.

Comment: My question is:how to deduce that $[f]$ is in the image of $\psi$ when we know the fact that $(f_1\cdot\bar{g_1})\cdot(g_1\cdot f_2\cdot\bar{g_2})\cdots(g_{m-1}\cdot f_m)$ is homotopic to $f$?

Comment: In that case the $f_i = g_{i-1} \cdot f_i \cdot g_i$ are loops which are contained in $A_i$. Then clearly $\psi([f_1]\ldots[f_n]) = i_1([f_1])\ldots.i_n([f_n]) = [f]$.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: $\psi([f_1]\ldots[f_n]) = i_1([f_1])\ldots.i_n([f_n])=[f]$,you mean $i_k([f_k])=[f_k]$?but as you menntioned above,the homomorphism induced by inclusionmay not be injective,how we conclude that inclusion?